# Absolute reference to reference_docx in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Last year, I ran a programme that renders a Word Document based on a reference document.

```
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: "Z:/04.Software/02.R_Functions/RMD_dashboards/report.docx"
```

This year, it doesn't work (I must have updated something along the way). Rather than taking the reference_docx value as an absolute reference, it has swapped to a relative reference, and expects it to be in the same location as the save location.

This is not what I want - I want the reference document to be in a standard location, regardless of what RMD file I run.

Is there some way of changing RMD or the `render` function so that it accepts relative references rather than absolute?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use relative references too.

Your **absolute** way:

```
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: "Z:/04.Software/02.R_Functions/RMD_dashboards/report.docx"
```

**relative** one

```
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: "../RMD_dashboards/report.docx"
```

**relative** two

```
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: "report.docx"
```

All methods should work.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem that I have is that it's using the first way, but it's trying to use C:/My Documents/Z:/04.Software/02.R_Functions...

Comment: @DanielV It is strange. Maybe try to delete .RData. But I'm not sure